# Need an advice to display large amount of data Android

Tags: android, user-interface

Need an advice about one thing: I'm working on one application, which needs to display a lot of information about some items, which can be of different types with some similar attributes and some extra. Something like this:

```
Trade Mark
1. id : 211
2. name : Bla bla bla
3. Color : green
...
...
..
44. location

Invention
1. id : 211
2. name : Bla bla bla
3. Category : vehicle 
...
...
..
44. location
```

So all these items are displayed in one List, but when you select one, it should show the more detailed information.

My question is: What is the best practice to display the data? should I create different activities for each category? Or should I create one activity and hide/show attributes related to the particular category? Or may be you can bring me to the light with showing something more effective. Gonna be very appreciated. Thanks! =)

Comment: Have you consider using ExpandableListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best practice to display the data?

Use a `ListView`/`GridView` with ViewHolder pattern.

> should I create different activities for each category? Or should I
>   create one activity and hide/show attributes related to the particular
>   category?

Its really up to you, using a layout with `show-hide` method will decrease the number of `classes` in your project **but** make the code a little harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

`ExpandableListView` is the way to go. No need for multiple activities or fragments. If you so wish you can make a fragment that contains the `ExpandableListView` but that's it - no need for multiple activities. If you are working with tablet's as well, then you might want to have a `detailed` fragment for the list item details when you click on a particular item. No more, no less, imho.